# GUI calculation issue

Tags: java

i have been trying for ever now trying to figure out why my code for my JFrame wont show the correct calculations! When i add all the numbers in windows Calculator they are correct but when i use my program it is different and incorrect. In my program i get the answer 520420 instead of 52420,5 which i get in windows calculator. Could someone please tell me where i am going wrong with my program and get the correct answer i would get with windows calculator?
Bellow is my calculate button which adds numbers to the total price if a check box is selected!

```
private void calculatorBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   double price = 0;

    if(shoesTK.isSelected())
    {
     price = price + 120;
    }
    if(cricketBatCK.isSelected())
    {
       price = price + 300;
    }
    if(bikeCK.isSelected())
    {
        price = price + 20000;
    }
    if(watchCK.isSelected())
    {
        price = price + 500000;
    }
    if(plasticBagCK.isSelected())
    {
        price = price + 0.50;
    }

    System.out.println(price);
    String total = Double.toString(price);
    totalTXT.setText(total);
}
```

Output of my program with the total being incorrect.
[image]

Output of windows calcultor and the result i want.

[image]

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Stewart Clay How do you get `52420.5` when your watch is 500000?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful i added pictures to help explain.

Comment: I vote to close this as this is just a typo error of having extra zeroes from the OP. Nothing related to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue will probably not be of any value for anyone else in the future -- it's a simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(bikeCK.isSelected())
{
    price = price + 20000;
}
if(watchCK.isSelected())
{
    price = price + 500000;
}
```

You've got a trailing zero too much in both of these cases. It should be `2000` and `50000` respectively.

Also, in your text you say that you get `520420` but your screen shot actually shows `520420.5` so it looks like the plastic bag is handled correctly.